# Aligning custom checkbox issue css

Tags: html, css, checkbox, styles

I am tying to align the text of the right of my checkbox. Currently the text is appearing in multiple lines.

I have tried changing the width and giving it a fixed width:

```
.checkbox span.custom  {
  margin-left: 34px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px; // MY TRY
}
```

but it is changing the size of the checkbox not the text next to it.

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
}

.checkbox {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 24px;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.checkbox input {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 6px;
  opacity: 0;
  outline: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1px;
  top: 1px;
  width: 10px;
}

.checkbox .custom {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 24px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 24px;
}

.checkbox span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 34px;
  margin-top: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
}

.checkbox input:checked:not(:disabled) + .custom {
  background-color: #0574ac;
  border-color: #0574ac;
}

.checkbox span {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.checkbox span.custom  {
  margin-left: 34px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px; // MY TRY
}

.checkbox span.custom .radio span.custom {
  margin-left: 34px;
  margin-right: 34px;
  display: flex;
}

.radio input:checked + .custom:after {
  background-color: #0574ac;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<label for="checkbox1" class="checkbox">
      <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" role="checkbox" /><span class="custom">Checkbox 1</span>
</label>
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tkuyxko4/)**

Comment: umm why some much css? do you just want the label to be aligned with the checkbox?

Comment: Yes I need the label to be aligned with the checkbox. label on the left and checkbox on its right @AdamBuchananSmith

Comment: @user4756836, I noticed just now on the comment here that you wanted to switch between the label text and the checkbox. I added an example for that too, you are welcome to check the update in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the `position: absolute` of the `.checkbox .custom` and also the `width: 24px` that you have there is causing you problems.

Here is a working version:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
}

.checkbox {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 27px;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.checkbox input {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  margin: 6px;
  opacity: 0;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  left: 1px;
  top: 1px;
  line-height: 26px;
}
.checkbox input#checkbox2, .checkbox input#checkbox3 {
  opacity: 1;
}
.checkbox3 {
  display: flex;
}
.checkbox3 span {
  order: -1;
}
.checkbox .custom {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 27px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.checkbox span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 34px;
  margin-top: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
}

.checkbox.checkbox3 span.custom {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.checkbox input:checked:not(:disabled) + .custom {
  background-color: #0574ac;
  border-color: #0574ac;
}

.checkbox span {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.checkbox span.custom  {
  margin-left: 34px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.checkbox span.custom .radio span.custom {
  margin-left: 34px;
  margin-right: 34px;
  display: flex;
}

.radio input:checked + .custom:after {
  background-color: #0574ac;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
}
```

```html
<label for="checkbox1" class="checkbox">
  <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" role="checkbox" /><span class="custom">Checkbox 1</span>
</label>
<br />
<label for="checkbox2" class="checkbox">
  <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" role="checkbox" /><span class="custom">Checkbox 2</span>
</label>
<br />
<label for="checkbox3" class="checkbox checkbox3">
  <input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox" role="checkbox" /><span class="custom">Checkbox 3</span>
</label>
```

> I'm not sure why you set the `opacity: 0` for the checkbox itself so I added an example with the checkbox without the `opacity: 0`

## Update

I notices in the comments that you want the label to be on the left and the checkbox on the right so I also added an example for that using the flexbox model.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <label>Simple label</label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't even have a checkbox. Also it doesn't include the custom blue effect of the OP's example.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've given hides the actual native checkbox with `opacity: 0` and then uses the selector `:checked` to change the `background-color` of the `span.custom` element when the checkbox is checked.

Your attempt is doing exactly what you've told it.

If you want text to appear outside of the area which becomes blue when checked, you need to completely re-think your design of the checkbox, because it's impossible to work this way without drastically changing the markup, and the whole logic of the way it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this? it is really hard to tell though https://jsfiddle.net/tkuyxko4/1/

Comment below if you want something changed.

HTML

```
<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" role="checkbox" />
<label for="checkbox1" class="checkbox">Checkbox 1</label>
```

CSS

```
label { 
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  background-color: #0574ac;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
}
```